Github auto deploy project with submodules on hostinger using webhook
I have a project that have a submodule, i want to auto deploy project with submodule on hostinger using github webhooks.
I tried to set webhook and it works file, but it deploy only main project not submodule. I want whenever i push to git, it auto deploy submodule aswell.
